# Switching shaders in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader

I have a problem with a program written in webgl and I don't know how to debug it because the browser console shows no errors. Webgl is drawing nothing at all.

I have the following set of shaders:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;    
varying vec3 vEye;
varying vec3 vNormal;
uniform vec3 uLightDirection;    // Vector direccion de la luz
uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor; // Color de la luz direcional

uniform vec3 uColShadeless;
uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;
uniform float uKAmbiente;
uniform vec3 uColDifuso;
uniform float uKDifuso;
uniform vec3 uColEspecular;
uniform float uKEspecular;
uniform float uGlossiness;

void main(void) 
{
    vec3 normal = normalize(vNormal);
    float mLambert = max(dot(normal, uLightDirection), 0.0);
    vec3 vLuzLambert = uDirectionalColor * mLambert;

    vec3 r = 2.0 * max(dot(normal, uLightDirection), 0.0) * normal - uLightDirection;
    //vec3 r = reflect(uLightDirection, normal); // <- Da glossines del otro lado también
    float specular = pow(max(dot(r, normalize(vEye)), 0.0), uGlossiness) ;
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    vec3 componenteShadeless = uColShadeless * textureColor.rgb * uColDifuso;             // luz autoiluminada * colores difusos
    vec3 componenteAmbiente = uKAmbiente * uAmbientColor * textureColor.rgb * uColDifuso; // k% * luz ambiente * colores difusos
    vec3 componenteDifusa = uKDifuso * textureColor.rgb * uColDifuso * vLuzLambert;
    vec3 componenteEspecular = uKEspecular * specular * uColEspecular ;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(componenteShadeless + componenteAmbiente + componenteDifusa + componenteEspecular, textureColor.a);
}
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vEye;
varying vec3 vNormal;

uniform vec2 aUVOffset;

void main(void) 
{

        // Transformamos al vértice al espacio de la cámara
        vec4 pos_camera_view = uViewMatrix * uModelMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        // Transformamos al vértice al espacio de la proyección
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * pos_camera_view;
        // Coordenada de textura
        vTextureCoord.x = aTextureCoord.x + aUVOffset.x;
        vTextureCoord.y = aTextureCoord.y + aUVOffset.y;

        // Para iluminación
        vEye = -vec3(pos_camera_view.xyz);
        vNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
}
</script>

<script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aPositionL;
        attribute vec3 aNormalL;
        attribute vec3 aTangentL;
        attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

        uniform mat4 uMatrixMVP;
        uniform mat4 uMatrixMV;

        varying vec4 vPositionV;
        varying vec3 vNormalV;
        varying vec3 vTangentV;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord;

        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

        uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
        uniform mat3 uNMatrix;
        varying vec3 vNormal;

        uniform vec2 aUVOffset;
        void main(void) 
        {

        // Transformamos al vértice al espacio de la cámara
        vec4 pos_camera_view = uViewMatrix * uModelMatrix * vec4(aPositionL, 1.0);
        // Transformamos al vértice al espacio de la proyección
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * pos_camera_view;

        vNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
        vPositionV = uMatrixMV * vec4(aPositionL, 1.0);
        vNormalV = (uMatrixMV * vec4(aNormalL, 0.0)).xyz;
        vTangentV = (uMatrixMV * vec4(aTangentL, 0.0)).xyz;
        vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
</script>

<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
        #endif

        uniform sampler2D uColorSampler;
        uniform sampler2D uNormalSampler;
        uniform float uTime;

        varying vec4 vPositionV;
        varying vec3 vNormalV;
        varying vec3 vTangentV;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord;

        void main(void) {
            vec3 diffuse = texture2D(uColorSampler, vTexCoord).rgb;
            vec3 normalT = texture2D(uNormalSampler, vTexCoord).xyz;
            normalT.y = 1.0 - normalT.y;
            normalT = 2.0 * normalT - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            normalT.z *= 10.0;

            vec3 binormalV = cross(vNormalV, vTangentV);
            vec3 normalV = normalT.x * vTangentV + normalT.y * binormalV + normalT.z * vNormalV;

            normalV = normalize(normalV);
            vec3 lightV = normalize(vec3(10.0 * cos(uTime), 10.0, 10.0 * sin(uTime)));

            float d = dot(normalV, lightV);
            float s = dot(reflect(-lightV, normalV), normalize(-vPositionV.xyz));
            s = pow(s, 30.0);

            vec3 color = diffuse * (0.1 + 0.5 * d + 0.4 * s);

            gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
        }
```

So vs and fs are shaders used to draw a surface with a normal map texture. I use shader-fs and shader-vs for the rest of the code.

The following code is used to init shaders and change them:

```
function initShaders()
{
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    initShaders2();
}

function changeShaderBasic()
{

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgramMap);

    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aPositionL);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aNormalL);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aTangentL);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aTexCoord);

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

    shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.ViewMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uViewMatrix");
    shaderProgram.ModelMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uModelMatrix");
    shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNMatrix");
    shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");

    shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uAmbientColor"); // Color ambiente
    shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uLightDirection"); // Direccion de la luz
    shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uDirectionalColor"); // Color de la luz

    shaderProgram.shadelessColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uColShadeless");
    shaderProgram.ambientKUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uKAmbiente");
    shaderProgram.diffuseColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uColDifuso");
    shaderProgram.diffuseKUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uKDifuso");
    shaderProgram.specularColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uColEspecular");
    shaderProgram.specularKUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uKEspecular");
    shaderProgram.specularGlossiness = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uGlossiness");    

    shaderProgram.uvOffsetUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "aUVOffset");

}



function initShaders2() {

            var vs = getShader(gl,'vs');
            var fs = getShader(gl,'fs');

            shaderProgramMap = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgramMap, vs);
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgramMap, fs);
            gl.linkProgram(shaderProgramMap);

            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgramMap, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                alert('Could not link the shader normal program.');
                return;
            }
}


function changeShaderNormal()
{
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgramMap);

    shaderProgramMap.ViewMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgramMap, "uViewMatrix");
    shaderProgramMap.ModelMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgramMap, "uModelMatrix");
    shaderProgramMap.aPositionL = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'aPositionL');
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aPositionL);
    shaderProgramMap.aNormalL = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'aNormalL');
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aNormalL);
    shaderProgramMap.aTangentL = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'aTangentL');
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aTangentL);
    shaderProgramMap.aTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'aTexCoord');
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgramMap.aTexCoord);
    shaderProgramMap.uMatrixMVP = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'uMatrixMVP');
    shaderProgramMap.uMatrixMV = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'uMatrixMV');
    shaderProgramMap.uColorSampler = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'uColorSampler');
    shaderProgramMap.uNormalSampler = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'uNormalSampler');
    shaderProgramMap.uTime = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgramMap, 'uTime');
}
```

So I call the function "changeShaderBasic" first, and when I want to draw a surface with a normal map I do something like this:

```
changeShaderNormal();
*Draw the surface*
changeShaderBasic();
```

If I delete that part of the code it works- So the shaders shader-fs and shader-vs seem to be working fine. The problem seems to be the other shaders (vs and fs) or the function that switchs between shaders.

I have omited the part of the code which the program uses to create textures.

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I don't know how to find the problem.

Comment: You should really check the return values of `getAttribLocation` for `-1` and `getUniformLocation` for `null` in case they are not found.

Comment: I've just checked them all and the problem persists. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I see that you `disableVertexAttribArray( shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute )`, but do not enable it on `shaderProgramMap.vertexPositionAttribute`; you haven't initialized it either. And the same for the tex coords and vertex normals.

Comment: I've never tried this (switching shaders) before and I don't understand you. shaderProgramMap doesn't have that attribute (vertexPositionAttribute). Should both shaders have the same attributes?

Comment: Press control-F, type `VertexPosition` and search through them. You'll see that you define `aVertexPosition` in both `shader-vs` and `vs`, so yes, you'll have to initialize that attribute (and others) also in `shaderProgramMap` (the `vs` and `fs` shaders). I ran into this problem myself, because the code wasn't clear anymore, so I wrote a function, mapping a regular expression over the shader source code, extracting the attributes and uniforms (and their types), so I can do runtime checks to see if all parameters are set (and if non-existing parameters were requested).

Comment: [You might find this useful](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that some shader parameters of `shaderProgramMap` are not enabled. For example, there is

> ```
> shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
> gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
> ```

and

> ```
> gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
> ```

but nothing for `shaderProgramMap`, which' script also has the `aVertexPosition` attribute.

When you're starting to get these kinds of problems, where *you* can't find what's wrong with code *you wrote*, it is because the code is no longer clear: the overview is lost. 
There's duplicate code: the same thing is done twice, namely to compile, link, and configure a Shader. Then, it's time to refactor: extract all duplicate code, and parameterize what's different.

There are many possible steps. One is to abstract the shader parameters: the `attributes` and `uniforms`.
The code below will produce a parameter hashmap with information about all the parameters in the shader source. Note, it may not cover all possibilities, but it is merely to give you an idea.

```
function initShaderParams( gl, shaderProgram, vs, fs )
{
    /** We'll be returning this: */
    var params = {
        uniform:{},
        attribute:{},

        uniforms: function(arr) {
            for ( var a in arr )
                if ( params.uniform[a] )
                    params.uniform[ a ].set( arr[a] );
                else throw new Error("unknown uniform '"+a+"' referenced in shader " + vs+"+"+fs
                    + ";\navailable uniforms: " + Object.keys(params.uniform)
                );
        },

        enable: function() {
            for ( var a in this.attribute )
                gl.disableVertexAttribArray( this.attribute[a] );
        }

        // disable: ....
    };


    /** returns a function to set the value of a uniform given it's type */
    function getUniformFN( type ) {
        switch ( type ) {
            case 'vec2': return function(v){gl.uniform2f( this.loc, false, v[0], v[1] );};
            case 'mat4': return function(v){gl.uniformMatrix4fv( this.loc, false, v );};
            default:
                throw new Error("unknown uniform type " + type + " in shader " + vs+"+"+fs );
        }
    }

    /** same, for attributes. */
    function getAttributeFN( type ) {
        switch ( type ) {
            case 'vec2': return function(v){ gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, v ); gl.vertexAttribPointer( this.loc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); };
            case 'vec3': return function(v){ gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, v ); gl.vertexAttribPointer( this.loc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); };
            case 'vec4': return function(v){ gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, v ); gl.vertexAttribPointer( this.loc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); };
            default:
                throw new Error("unknown uniform type " + type + " in shader " + vs+"+"+fs );
        }
    }

    /** Utility method to map a regex callback */
    function regexMap(regex, text, callback) {
        while ((result = regex.exec(text)) != null)
            callback(result);
    }

    // extract parameters:

    var src = vs + fs;

    regexMap(/(uniform)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)(\[\d+\])?\s*;/g, src, function(groups) {
        var loc = gl.getUniformLocation( shaderProgram, groups[3] );
        if ( loc == null ) {
            console.warn("declared ", groups[0], " not used" );
            return;
        }

        params.uniform[ groups[3] ] = {
            type: groups[2],
            loc:  loc,
            set:  getUniformFN( groups[2] )
       };
    } );

    regexMap(/(attribute)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*;/g, src, function(groups) {
        var loc = gl.getAttribLocation ( shaderProgram, groups[3] );
        if ( loc == -1 ) {
            console.warn("declared ", groups[0], " not used" );
            return;
        }
        params.attribute[ groups[3] ] = {
            type: groups[2],
            loc:  loc,
            set:  getAttributeFN( groups[2] )
        };
    } );

    return params;
}
```

Calling this method you'll have access to the shader parameters, and you can
iterate over them, or set them all at once:

```
var params = initShaderParams( gl, shaderProgram, vsSource, fsSource );

params.uniforms( {
    uViewMatrix: ...,
    uModelMatrix: ...,
    ...
} );
```

That way, the code becomes more clear, and it will make it easier to spot what is missing. You could even write a function to do it for you: [calculate the intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) of the `params.uniforms` keys and the given parameters to see if all of them are specified, or keep track of whether they are set using a setter function.
Of course, there are many other ways; you could also create a `Shader` class and override methods.

Copy-paste coding leads to unmaintainable code. As a rule of thumb, whenever you have to program something twice, you're doing it once too often.